# How to create a dynamic Django choice field

Tags: python, django, list

I am trying to generate a list to populate choices for a form. This list will be dynamic and will depend on what choices have been created by other users. Here is an example of the model the list should derive from:

```
#models.py
class User(models.Model):
    brewery_you_work_for = models.CharField(choises=ALL_THE_BREWERIES_IN_THE_WORLD)
    username = models.CharField()
```

I want the form to be something like this:

```
#forms.py
class BestBrewery(forms.Form):
    vote = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BREWERIES_A_USER_WORKS_FOR)
```

What I want to do is have a list of all the breweries in the world for some users to select as the brewery they work for. Then I want to generate a list for other users to vote as the best brewery.

Lets say I have 3 users that claim they work the Sierra Nevada, 2 users that claim they work for Budweiser, and 5 users that claim they work for Coors.

I want to generate a list of breweries that would look like this:

```
(
'Budweiser',
'Coors,
'Sierra Nevada',
)
```

Note the alphabetical order and no repeated brewery listings.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass an extra `user` argument when initialising the form. Normally like this if you are using view functions:

```
form = BestBrewery(request.user)
```

If you are using Class Based Views you should override the `get_form_kwargs` method in your view:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(MyView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user

    return kwargs
```

Your form should look like this:

```
class BestBrewery(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BestBrewery, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['vote'].choices = (
            user.brewery_you_work_for,
            user.get_brewery_you_work_for_display()
        )
```

Just note that to override the `choices` field you need to provide tuples containing the value for the form and the text to be shown in the dropdown.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think u can set "choices" as result of function.
I tried like that:

```
def yolo():
    # there we will get stats from db and return choices depends on stats
    first_query = 1  # there U will use more complicated logic :)
    second_query = 3
    if first_query > second_query:
        return (1, 2, 3)
    else:
        return (1, 3)

class Event(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(primary_key=True)
    count_of_updates = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
    yolos = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=yolo())
```

And, for being sure U can check ur choices with something ugly:

```
choices = s._meta.get_field_by_name('yolos')[0].choices
print choices
```

Order and other things u can set in func logic :)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the choices are not updated during runtime, only on app restart

Answer (score 4):

In your Form, you can change the choices of your field in the init.

```
class BestBrewery(forms.Form):
    vote = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BestBrewery, self).__init__(*arg, **kwargs)

        # get the choices from where you need
        choices = (...)
        self.fields['vote'].choices = choices
```