# How to call call a static function from the same Model in the Model upon initialisation? DJANGO PYTHON

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

So long story short, I have a Car model and a CarVersion model and I want the user to have the ability to choose from the availble car versions saved in the database, through a html select field.

I cannot understand how to dynamically generate the choices field from the CarVersion model. I have the function, but I cannot call it inside the Car model.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    choices = get_choices()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    version = models.ForeignKey(CarVersion, choices=get_choices(), on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    
    @staticmethod
    def get_choices():
        options = CarVersion.objects.all().values_list("pk", "name")
        try:
            if not options:
                return [(0, "No versions in database. Call your administrator.")]
        except ProgrammingError:
            return [(0, "No versions in database. Call your administrator.")]
        return [(1, "Test")]
```

I want to call the function `get_choices` in

`version = models.ForeignKey(CarVersion, choices=get_choices(), on_delete=models.RESTRICT)`
but I don't know how to do that while the function is declared to the model. If I define it outside of the model, it works, but there must surely be a better way that im missing, rather than cluttering my models.py file with a bunch of model specific functions.

P.S.`get_choices` is not finished but as soon as I can call it, I will deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank Daniil for his contribution, for without it, I would have never been able to ask the correct question for my problem, which is:

How to dynamically generate a choices field.

The answer to that question can be found at:
[How to create a dynamic Django choice field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020023/how-to-create-a-dynamic-django-choice-field)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against doing it this way for several reasons. The `choices` parameter on the model field is for validating data you could potentially add to the database.

Besides that, the way yo write it, the function that fetches the `CarVersion` objects is called **when the module is loaded**. This is a bad idea. You may want to import the module in some place at a time when you don't even have a database connection yet.

The proper way to to this, since your intent is to generate options in an HTML form for the user, would be to rely on the foreign key capabilities of the Django Forms. The [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) should already do what you need.

PS: In fact the `ModelChoiceField` is automatically instantiated, when you create a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform) from a Model that has a `ForeignKey` field. See the list of field conversion on the `ModelForm` page.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As per the documentation of ModelChoiceField in a ModelForm:

```If the model field has choices set, then the form field’s widget will be set to Select, with choices coming from the model field’s choices. 
```
I understand that the choices are to be passed to the model. My question is how to do that dynamically, instead of hardcoding them like the examples show? I want my choices to be dynamically generated by whatever is in the CarVersion table up to this point.

Comment: Answer to the question at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020023/how-to-create-a-dynamic-django-choice-field

Thank you